# Use stream to get list with ids

Tags: java

I want to implement a search using stream from this code:

DTO:

```
public class FilterNewDTO
{
    private Integer id;
    private Integer terminal_id;
    private Integer position;
    private Integer parent_id;
}
```

Sort:

```
List<Filters> filterList = filterService.findFiltersByTerminalId(terminalId);

for (int i = 0; i < newFiltersPositionsList.size(); i++) {
    Filters filter = filterList.findById(newFiltersPositionsList.get(i).getId());
    filter.setPosition(newFiltersPositionsList.get(i).getPosition());
    filterService.save(filter);
}
```

I tried this:

```
filterList.stream()
    .filter(filter -> filter.findById(newFiltersPositionsList.get(i).getId()));
```

But I get error `The method findById(int) is undefined for the type RiskFilters` Can you guide me how to find the element into the list `filterList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter method expects a Predicate object as parameter. From the Stream API: `Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate);` so T, which is a generic type, will assume the same type of your list. So your code would look like this:

```
List<Filters> filteredList =  filterList.stream().filter(new Predicate<Filters>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Filter f) {
            return f.id == some-id;
        }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As seen from the Predicate class, it is a FunctionalInterface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Predicate<T> {

    boolean test(T t)
};
```

If the `test(T t)` method returns `true`, the current object will be kept in the stream.
Thus, this could be rewritten to a lambda expression, just like this:

```
List<Filters> filteredList =  filterList.stream().filter(f -> f.id == some-id).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: hm... something like this? https://pastebin.com/0DZ5aQTD but I need to get just one item not a list I suppose.

Comment: So, instead of the collect method, call a findAny. It will return an Optional<Filters> and then you just have to check if it has something. Optional<Filters> op = filterList.stream().filter(f -> f.id == some-id).findAny();

Comment: Now I get `Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`

Comment: That's why you are using the i variable at the for loop inside the lambda function, and that's not allowed. You can use an AtomicInteger to wrap your i variable, because atomic objects can be used inside lambda expressions

Answer (score 0):

Change `filter()` code as below.

```
filterList.stream()
    .filter(flr -> flr.id == <<id>>);
```

Comment: I created this `RiskFilters filter = filterList.stream()
     .filter(filtr -> newFiltersPositionsList.get(i).getId() == (filtr.getId()))
     .findAny()
     .orElse(null);` but I get Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final